# Extended web application pointing to root site collection, Can point to another site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-application, extended

I have a web application running on port 443 https with windows authentication, machine name is "localspdev"
I have following site collections

```
/ (Root site collection)

site1.dev (HNSC)

site2.dev (HNSC)
```

If I browse "https://localspdev" I get root site collection, which is fine. I can browse site1 and site2 as well

I am extending web application to extranet zone with forms and windows authentication enabled, port is 443, https and host header is "extranet.dev"

when I browse "https://extranet.dev", root site collection comes up, which I don't want, I can create 1 more extranet HNSC but how can I configure "https://extranet.dev" to open/link new extranet site collection?

Answer (score 0):

Zones represent different logical paths to gain access to the same sites in a web application. Each web application can include as many as five zones. 
In simple words, zones are used when you want to access the **same content** with different authentication or URL. Basically it allows you to treat a single site differently based on what URL is used to access the site.

So if you want different site collection with  then you need another HSNC with that url.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx#planzone